# EasyAR Native Android Show image instead of video

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am using EasyAR to make some augmented reality apps. It has some built in class for displaying videos, but I want to show some images on screen when EasyAR detects any matches, so that user can interact with them. Is there any way to do that? And to be clear I don't want to use Unity, just pure Android.

Answer (score 1):

I think this project has what you need (it's not mine):

- https://github.com/khoben/studyAR

Just adapt the texture loading code, and use this `ImageRenderer` class. I did the same, and it works like a charm.